# How to make Titra docker image answer https?

Tags: meteor

I've got a test installation of [Titra](https://titra.io/) on a local system, and I've got it answering http on port 80 with this docker-compose file:

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  titra:
    image: kromit/titra
    container_name: titra
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - ROOT_URL=http://timesheet
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb/titra
      - PORT=3000
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    restart: always
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /root/titradb:/data/db
```

That works, but I'd kind of like the thing to answer https instead, but I'm not that familiar with [Titra](https://titra.io/) itself, nor [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) (the framework it's written in), and my poking around the available documentation hasn't turned up anything about https for self-hosted Titra instances.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a nginx reverse proxy to your docker-compose file:

```
reverse:
  container_name: reverse
  hostname: reverse
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./nginx/conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
titra:
  image: kromit/titra
  container_name: titra
  hostname: titra
  depends_on:
    - mongodb
  environment:
    - ROOT_URL=https://timesheet
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb/titra
    - PORT=3000
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  restart: always

mongodb:
  image: mongo:4.4
  container_name: mongodb
  hostname: mongodb
  restart: always
  volumes:
   - /srv/mongodb/:/data/db
```

Your nginx should be configured with a *.conf like containing something like this:
upstream titra {
server        titra:3000;
}

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name timesheet;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/timesheet/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/timesheet/privkey.pem;
    

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://titra;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I have a similar setup and it works fine. It's based loosely on

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/docker-nginx-letsencrypt-easy-secure-reverse-proxy-40165ba3aee2/

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to test this idea - Titra turned out to not work for us for other reasons.